# Mapping foreign key into the same table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping

I have a db with 5 data
- id (PK, int)
- question (varchar)
- result (varchar)
- left_id (int)
- right_id (int)

and 2 foreign keys into the same table
- left_id -> id
- right_id -> id

How can i map foreign key ? with @one-to-one or @many-to-one ?

for the time being my hbm like this

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.beans.Nodes" table="node">
        <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="question" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="question" />
        </property>
        <property name="result" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="result" />
        </property>


        <one-to-one name="left" class="com.beans.Nodes" access="field"></one-to-one>
        <one-to-one name="right" class="com.beans.Nodes" access="field"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Like this, my project starts.But if i put column left/right_id my project stops because I have 2 identical column. While for me, i just put id, question and result column with my foreign keys ...

here my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE "id INT auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
              question varchar(250),
              result varchar(250),
              left_id INT,
              foreign key (left_id) references node(id) on delete cascade,
              right_id INT,
              foreign key (right_id) references node(id) on delete cascade"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your table structure

Comment: ok, i just poster my table structure. Thanks

Comment: Your hbm entry should be something like <one-to-one name="left_id" class="com.beans.Nodes" constrained="true"></one-to-one> and make sure there is an attribute named left_id in the Nodes class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @JoinColumn like this

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "LEFT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public Nodes getLeftNodes() {
    return leftNodes;
}


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "RIGHT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public Nodes getRightNodes() {
    return rightNodes;
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But i did not need a left/right_id integer ? How can keep left_id in my object if there is no variable ? For example i would like to (node.getQuestion().getLeftid()). Thanks

Comment: It will not have a separate integer for left_id & rigt_id. It's a foreign key of the class Nodes. so its Nodes.id of another Nodes record. To give a right example you can assume employee having a relation with manager who is again an employee. So a employee would have a manager_id which is another employee_id.

Answer (score 0):

I do(node.getQuestion().getLeft_id() and see the result.

But i can't insert a new left_id because i dont have left_id integer.

here my insert method

```
public void insert_question(String question, int left ) throws HibernateException
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Nodes node = new Nodes();
            Nodes test = new Nodes();

            node.setQuestion(question);
            node.setLeftNodes(left.getLeftNodes().getId_node());


            session.saveOrUpdate(node);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Without int left, i can insert but i dont have left_id. 
And if i add

```
node.setLeftNodes(left.getLeftNodes().getId_node());
```

Eclipse told me that "Cannot invoke getLeftNodes() on the primitive type int" because left_id integer is not exist.

tkanks